# Toplevel window in Python keeps appearing under the root window

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a toplevel window that keeps appear underneath the root window, which is pretty annoying. Any idea how to make sure that the toplevel gets the focus when the function is called?

```
def setup(self):
    self.setup_step = 1
    setup_window = Toplevel(self)
    setup_window.config(bg = "#000000", height = "600",  width = "850")
    setup_window.title("RoastMaster Setup")
    setup_window.geometry("800x600")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by making the toplevel window transient.

Comment: Making it transient is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You might try raising it and giving it focus. It could be that you window manager wants the window with focus to always be on top.